# Installing updates on new installation of Windows 7, display turns off

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, windows-update, .net-framework

Yesterday I started to reinstall Windows 7 32-bit version on my computer. I got to the point where I needed to install the updates, and so I downloaded and installed them, and after restarting the machine, I installed some more of them. At that point it was too late and I needed to sleep so I let the computer install the updates and then automatically shut off.

Today, when I restarted my computer, at first it started but then got stuck on the starting screen. A little bit after the display turned off with the message "out of range !" on the screen. So I decided to restart my computer (probably not a good idea) after waiting for some time. It started normally at first, but when I went to the Windows Updates -section and approved the installation of .NET Framework (can't remember which one), the screen shut off again. Now I've been waiting for at least an hour, but the display is still off. What should I do?

Comment: Restart the computer -> just before the computer gets to the Windows logo press `F8` -> Select `Start in VGA / low resolution mode` -> let your graphics card drivers finish installing -> set an appropriate resolution for your monitor.

Comment: Closing since a loose connection is akin to a typo

Answer (score 2):

Okay, now I feel like someone with brain activity of an amoeba. At some point the VGA cable had come off (I guess I will never figure out how) and that's the reason the screen was unresponsive. Thank you for your helpful answers and patience.

Comment: +1 for actually admitting. Most people would quietly delete the question!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should reinstall it again. Also you might have some hardware problems. Video Card or Memory is my guess.